# str_replace a defined number of spaces followed by a dot

Tags: r, dplyr

I have recently received hundreds of CSV files with many columns. I am facing problems with one of the columns, `p.value`. This column has values like `1.88737914186277e-14      .`, where the actual number is followed by exactly 6 spaces and then a dot. I want to replace all these within my dplyr pipe. How can I do this?

I have tried, for example, 
`df %>% dplyr::mutate(p.value=str_replace(p.value, "[      .]", ""))` but obviously is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use this: `str_replace(p.value, pattern = "\\s+\\[.]$", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern: `"\\s+\\.$"`. It detects one or more spaces (`\\s+`) and a dot right at the end of the string (`\\.$`)

```
 df %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(p.value = str_replace(p.value, pattern = "\\s+\\.$", ""))
```

Comment: @ip2018 It's very nice to be useful. If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the tickmark right below the score ;)

Comment: Oops, I thought I did. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Since p-values are more useful as numbers I would recommend using `readr::parse_number` which automatically recognizes and converts string digits:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(p.value = parse_number(p.value))
```